# Spring data JPA getById vs GetReferenceById

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Does anyone know why `getById` and `getReferenceById` work differently?
I'm using `JpaRepository` and the method `getReferenceById` doesn't throw `EntityNotFoundException` but getById throws this exception when the object doesn't exist

Answer (score 3):

getReferenceById returns a proxy and doesn't do a database call therefore no exception is called as JPA doesn't know if the entity with this ID exists.

getReferenceById executes EntityManager.getReference and the docs says:

> T getReference​(java.lang.Class entityClass, java.lang.Object
> primaryKey)
>
> Get an instance, whose state may be lazily fetched. If the
> requested instance does not exist in the database, the
> EntityNotFoundException is thrown when the instance state is first
> accessed. (The persistence provider runtime is permitted to throw the
> EntityNotFoundException when getReference is called.) The application
> should not expect that the instance state will be available upon
> detachment, unless it was accessed by the application while the entity
> manager was open.

Source: https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/entitymanager

Comment: pending on how the JPA persistence provider is implemented this is very likely to always return an instance and throw an jakarta.persistence.EntityNotFoundException on first access.

Comment: @matio No it's not

Comment: Yes, this is a copy pasted text feom doc.According to documentation it is.you can  refer to the documentation

Comment: @matio Hibernate and EclipseLink are returning a proxy. This works very reliable and I use it since many years

Comment: Since 2.7 it is pretty much depending on how the JPA persistence provider is implemented. Refer to the latest documentation. 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/main/spring-data-jpa/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.java#L132
BTW I am referring to JPA as the implementation while hibernate is the abstraction layer.

Comment: JPA is the specification. Hibernate and EclipseLink are implementations of this specification. If you what to know more read the spec https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.html

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when using only `getById` as a way to fetch the entity makes some major issues. Usually we prefer to use `getReferenceById` method instead to save some extra calls, as if we were doing such using `getById` there is an extra call to database.
Let’s consider we have a `Category` child entity that is associated with the parent `Product` entity via the `Product` reference in the `Category` entity. Means each product has multiple categories. The code block that adds a new category to our product using `productId` as reference is below:

```
public Category addNewCategory(String categoryName, Long productId) {           
    Category category = new Category()
        .setName(categoryName)
        .setProduct(productRepository.findById(productId)
            .orElseThrow(
                ()-> new EntityNotFoundException(
                    String.format(
                        "Product with id [%d] was not found!",
                        productId
                    )
                )
            )
        );

    categoryRepository.save(category);

    return category;
}
```

If you want to add a category to a product, you first need to call `findProductById` each time you insert a new `Category`. When you got the `Product` then you insert it as a reference to the `Category` entity.
In this case Spring Data JPA would generate the following sql:

```
SELECT
product0_.id AS id1_0_0_,
product0_.slug AS name2_0_0_,
product0_.title AS title3_0_0_
FROM
 product product0_
WHERE
 product0_.id = 1

SELECT nextval ('hibernate_sequence')

INSERT INTO category (
 product_id,
 name,
 id
)
VALUES (
 1,
 'book',
 1
)
```

This query was generated by the `findById` method call, which is meant to load the entity in the current Persistence Context. However, in our case, we don’t need that. We just want to save a new `Category` entity and set the product_id Foreign Key column to a value that we already know.

But, since the only way to set the underlying product_id column value is to provide a `Product` entity reference, that’s why many developers end up calling the `findById` method.

In our case, running this SQL query is unnecessary because we don’t need to fetch the parent Product entity. But how can we get rid of this extra SQL query?
We can use `getReferenceById` method instead.

```
public PostComment addNewCategory(String name, Long productId) {
    Category category = new Category()
       .setName(name)
       .setProduct(productRepository.getReferenceById(productId));

       categoryRepository.save(category);

       return category;
}
```

When calling the same `addNewCategory` method now, we see that the `Product` entity is no longer fetched as it will be fetched from a cached location where JPA holds entity Proxy. This way we can optimize our Spring applications that uses database intensively.

Comment: I think you better attach [the SOURCE](https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-data-jpa-findbyid/) and not to modify some wordings to treat it as your works. NVM if you are the author ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying seems a bit odd, as the implementation of the deprecated `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository#getById` just delegates to it's replacement, `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository#getReferenceById`.

As you can see in the implementation of that method (`org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository#getReferenceById`) it is directly using the `EntityManager#getReference` method.
When using Hibernate this normally only creates a Proxy, and just when you access one of the fields the Proxy fetches the real values from the DB - or throwing an `EntityNotFoundException` in case it does not exist.

Could it be that you changed something in your code, or you are being tricked by your debugger trying to display the `toString` of your method?